# Bash command to batch-process files using find and sorted by size

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am looking for the Linux command that batch-processes all files in the current directory, in the ascending order of the file sizes.

As a concrete example, my `hello.py` prints the file names:

```
print 'hello', sys.argv[1]
```

If my current directory has files `file1`, `file2`, and `file3`, with size(file1)<=size(file2)<=size(file3), then the Linux command I am looking for should output

```
hello, file1
hello, file2
hello, file3
```

For now, I use

```
find . -type f -exec python hello.py {} \;
```

But I do not see how to process files in the specific order on their sizes. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Just for your info, there is no such thing as a "Linux command". The things you invoke in a shell (e.g. Bash) are either programs (like `/bin/ls`) or shell commands (like `cd`). As such, you should always mention the actual shell you are using, as there are differences in syntax between them that are sometimes significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using ls

`ls` has an easy way to sort by size using the `-S` switch

```
for x in $(ls -S); do                    
    python hello.py $x
done
```

Or as a one-liner: `for x in $(ls -S); do python hello.py $x; done`

Or use `xargs`, like this: `ls -1 -S | xargs -n 1 python hello.py`, but careful because this breaks spaces in the filename into multiple files, more on that below*

### Using find without changing hello.py

```
find . -type f | xargs du | sort -n | cut -f 2 | xargs python hello.py
```

Explanation:

1. `du` annotates with the file's size
2. `sort` sorts by that size column
3. `cut` removes the extra size column, to keep only the second column which is the filename
4. `xargs` calls hello.py on each line

### Making the Python script accept pipes

```
# hello.py
import sys

def process(filename):
    print 'hello ', filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in sys.stdin.readlines():
        process(filename)
```

Now you can pipe outputs to it, e.g. :

```
find . -type f | xargs du | sort -n | cut -f 2 | python hello.py
```

<sub>* If you need to support filenames with spaces in them, we should use 0 terminated lines, so:</sub>

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du | ...
```

Comment: Is there possible to stick to 'find', and use pipeline maybe?

Comment: "ls -1 -S | xargs -n 1 hello.py" should do the job?
Maybe with a -R switch for the ls?

Comment: Sure, but I think he'd like to keep using `find`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!